# Can't extract values from text file in C

Tags: c, file, fgets, scanf

I have a text file of about 2000 lines of text wich are formated like this:

> 1 1 Name1 LastN1 58 c 1600 1310.40 6 1 0.22 2164.80 1 
>   2 1 Name2 LastN2 22 d 1700 1523.37 4 1 0.13 897.26 1 
>   3 1 Name3 LastN3 34 c 1600 1195.84 2 1 0.26 836.16 1 
>   .
>   . 
>   2000 3 NameX LastNX 46 d 6000 6000.00 1 0 0.00 0.00 1

What i want to do is read all those values from the text file and store them into arrays wich are :

```
int id          [2100];
char nombre [2100][30];
char apellido   [2100][30];
int edad        [2100];
int puesto      [2100];     char categoria  [2100];
int sueldoI     [2100];
float sueldoA   [2100];
int antiguedad  [2100];
int inscrito    [2100];
float aporte    [2100];
float ahorro    [2100]; 
int libre       [2100];
```

But when i'm trying to read them i get a lot of trash into the console

These are the ways i'm using to try to read and store them into the arrays :

```
//Way number 1
char linea[70];
while(fgets(linea,70,datos) != NULL){   
    flushall();
    sscanf(linea,"%d %d %s %s %d %c %d %f %d %d %f %f %d\n",&id[i],&puesto[i],&nombre[i],&apellido[i],&edad[i],&categoria[i],&sueldoI[i],&sueldoA[i],&antiguedad[i],&inscrito[i],&aporte[i],&ahorro[i],&libre[i]);      
    i++;
}

// Way number 2 in here i get linea the way it's intended to be but i can't figure
// out a way to split the string into the multiple values i need to store in the arrays

while(fgets(linea,70,datos) != NULL){
    printf("%s",linea);
}
```

This is the output i get in the first way:

[image: Way #1 output]

**EDIT:**

I've modified the size of the arrays from 2100 to 2000 and the program seems to behave better

Comment: Can you post some more code. Specifically, what have you declared `linea` as?

Comment: sure i'll add it to the question but linea is declared as `char linea[70];`

Comment: What is the output in the first way?

Comment: why 70? Your 2000 line is already 54 chars long, easy to imagine someone with a long last name would overflow it, then sscanf would get an incomplete line. Your test won't catch this because what you have there is essentially a stream copy, it will copy a single long line with multiple fgets() calls. fgets keeps newlines but does not append one if there isn't one.

Comment: i get: `2 **garbage**`, by garbage i mean a lot of funny ascii symbols

Comment: Replace all the `70` with `500`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the address-of operators from `&nombre[i]`, and `&apellido[i]`, they are arrays and you can just use the array name without the address-of to get the address of the first element:

```
sscanf(/*....*/, nombre[i], apellido[i], /*....*/);
```

Also, for strings, you should specify expected string length to scanf (size of your array - 1):

```
sscanf(linea, "... %29s %29s ....", /*....*/, nombre[i], apellido[i], /*....*/);
```

And you might be misusing `i`:

```
int main() {
  char linea[70];
  FILE *datos = fopen("datos", "r");
  int i= 0;
  while(fgets(linea,70,datos) != NULL){   
    sscanf(linea,"%d %d %29s %29s %d %c %d %f %d %d %f %f %d\n", &id[i], &puesto[i], 
        nombre[i], apellido[i],&edad[i],&categoria[i],&sueldoI[i],
        &sueldoA[i],&antiguedad[i],&inscrito[i],&aporte[i],&ahorro[i],   
        &libre[i]); 
    i++;
  } 

  i--;

  for (; i >= 0; i--) {
    printf("%d %s\n", id[i], nombre[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still getting garbage as an output

Comment: +1, but I would consider rephrasing the answer so that it doesn't sound like & is never necessary for arrays.  ("they are arrays and you can just use the array name without the address-of")  For example, `int a[5]; scanf("%d", a[0]);`

Comment: Added the size of the array to the `%s` now it looks like this `%29s` and still getting garbage

Comment: Still doesn't work, my guess is sscanf it's getting the wrong input

Comment: How are you printing them out?

Comment: I tried the way you did it on your for loop, and then i tried printing everything in the `i` position of every array and it still prints garbage